# onClick eclipse button

Tags: java, eclipse, button, onclick, swt

I use [Eclipse Button](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FButton.html)

```
List<Button> aButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();
button = new Button(buttonsComposite, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText(BTN_TEXT);
    aButtons.add(button);
```

and i have [listener](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2FSWT.html&anchor=CHECK)

```
makeButtonsListen(new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            handleButtonEvent(event);
        }
    });

private void makeButtonsListen(Listener listener) {
    for (Button button : aButtons) {
        button.addListener(SWT.Selection, listener);
    }
}
```

My problem is value of `event.widget == button` change after I let up button. How to do it onClick? I want to when click and hold value is changing. Currently it happens after I let button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to listen for the mouse-down event, then add the listener to `SWT.MouseDown` instead of `SWT.Selection`:

```
private void makeButtonsListen(Listener listener) {
    for (Button button : aButtons) {
        button.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1; Out of curiosity: why didn't you post an answer in the first place, but used a comment to pen down your solution and only did an answer after OP found it to be helpful?

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Because I wasn't sure I understood the question. My comment was based on a hunch.

Comment: Thanks for answering - fair enough. It's just that I've seen people getting attacked over posting answers that coincide with solutions-in-comments. It kind of discourages to use the answer system as intended if the solutions-in-comments can have that effect :) Maybe asking for clarification would be better in that case -- or just posting your hunch as an answer and deleting it again if it turns out to be a misunderstanding. For what it's worth, I don't want to tell you how to use SO, I'm just happy I finally got an explanation for such a case. Good day to you, and keep on helping :)

Comment: Oh, and please let me know if you want me to clean up my comments on your answer.